# Set of increasing/Decreasing functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A function f : N → N is increasing if f(n + 1) ≥ f(n) for all n and decreasing if
f(n + 1) ≤ f(n) for all n

Is the set of increasing functions countable or uncountable?
What about the set of decreasing functions?

I have a feeling the increasing functions are uncountable but im not sure to show it. Some injection to the Power set?

Comment: Sorry edited my post!

Comment: Hint: consider $g(n) = f(n+1)-f(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I know where this question is from!

**Hints:**

- Diagonal argument on the first. Use the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded above.
- A countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Thanks I think i can see how to do the second part however i'm not sure how to construct the diagonal argument with functions in the first, thanks for the hints!

Comment: @user116498 Suppose the functions can be listed as $\{f_1,f_2\cdots\} $ and consider $f_1(1),f_2(2)\cdots $.